# Access VBA Code Troubleshoot

Tags: ms-access

I have a database (CodeStorage) and in it i have a table where I store multiple codes, I have forms that I have created to insert data, search, and delete. I am working on the coding for the insert and I keep getting an error:

```
Run-time error '424':
Object Required
```

and it always highlights the code

```
    CodeStorage.Execute = "INSERT INTO KWTable(KW, Source, Code) " & _
    " VALUES(" & Me.text_key & ",'" & Me.txt_code & "','" & _
    Me.combo_source & "')"
```

The full code is,

```
    Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    'add data to table
    CodeStorage.Execute = "INSERT INTO KWTable(KW, Source, Code) " & _
    " VALUES(" & Me.text_key & ",'" & Me.txt_code & "','" & _
    Me.combo_source & "')"

    'refresh data in list on form
    TableSub.Form.Requery

    End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: CodeStorage appears to be the name of your database; it isn't automatically declared as an object variable of some type.

Comment: VBA appears to think that `CodeStorage` is an empty object variable, thus the "Object Required" error.

Answer (score 1):

To use the .Execute method you have to run it against a database object.
  So something like CurrentDb().Execute  "..SQL statement.."

More often I see DoCmd.RuNSQL used when constructing SQL strings for dynamic queries that are just touching tables within Access itself.  There are Pros, Cons, and gotcha's to each method.

Couple reference items that discuss the differences more in depth:
http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/RunSQL_vs_Execute
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/acc2000-docmd-runsql-vs-currentdb-execute-t2503687.html

Answer (score 1):

Depending on if you are using DAO in an .MDB/.ACCDB or ADO in an .ADP, change `CodeStorage` to `CurrentDB` or `CurrentProject.Connection` respectively.